# How do I truncate a Flex StyleableTextField after two lines?

Tags: apache-flex, text, label, truncate, flex4.5

In my Flex 4.5 mobile app, I have an actionScript item renderer (that derives from Flex's LabelItemRenderer). I want to fit in exactly 2 lines of text, and then truncate the rest. The width and height of the label are fixed and known statically.

How can I do this? The StyleableTextField.truncateToFit() method only works for one line of text.

I've set wordWrap = true, so the text now flows into the second line - but I need to truncate the text if it doesn't fit in two lines.

I need it to show all the text if there is only one line. (in both cases the label should be vertically middle-aligned in my renderer)

I know how to override layoutContents to do sizing and positioning etc of the StyleableTextField. So I'm looking specifically for ideas to implement custom text truncation with the StyleableTextField).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using something specific to the StyleableTextField try the s:Label. It has a property `maxDisplayedLines` which you could set to 2 and it will handle the truncation.

Comment: I'm happy to do that - but do you know how it will affect performance in item renderers in a mobile application?

Comment: Shouldn't be bad, personally I would not hesitate to do it (YMMV). Now in a browser application, with 50+- cells showing at a time, there can be a very slight lag.

Comment: Just tried that. Doesn't look like labels are getting rendered at all in item renderers!

Comment: Also, as I mentioned, this is a mobile application.

Comment: Never mind - I was not setting the text property properly! doh!

Comment: Using the label in the renderer does work - and for my case the perf seems ok. Thanks! :)

Comment: You will likely see a performance hit by using Label instead of StyleableTextField.  The most likely place to notice this is in scrolling performance: resetting text often in StyleableTextField is faster than Label.